I faced a problem after installing my flutter application on android
I only got this gray empty containers , i need an ergent help cause it's related to my graduation project
.....i try to install my app on android platform but containers are empty how can i solve this problem. Please help me cause this is my first app

Can you add your code snippet

I have a lot of pages

Do u need a sample of any page

Chances that somebody can help you with the information you provided so far are limited. I recommend reading How to ask and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example, as following the guidance in there will drastically increase the chances that someone can/will help.

I think it's because "you're using Expanded inside a Widget (Stack) who has its own fit."
See this: Pageview display grey screen when in release mode

Thank u i will check out my code again, wish this one help
